# check if n numbers are all odd or even using - + * operations only

Tags: math, sum, operations

is there a way to check N numbers if they are all odd or even **without using mod function %???** ,i can only use - + * functions.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And besides that, your question is not clear. What checks can you use, such as equality or inequality? What do you mean by "check N numbers"?

Comment: hi , i'm not trying to code , i'm looking for mathmatical idea only because i don't know if it can be done with only + - * operators, and yes i can check = < > != .

Answer (score 1):

So you can use addition, subtraction, multiplication, and comparisons. I'll also assume you can define functions, and your goal is to define two functions:

- The `evenList` function takes a list of numbers and returns true iff (if-and-only-if) the list contains only even numbers.
- The `oddList` function takes a list of numbers and returns true iff the list contains only odd numbers.

First let's define an `even` function that takes a single number and returns true iff the input is even:

```
even(i) = if (i == 0) true
          else if (i == 1) false
          else if (i > 1) even(i - 2)
          else /* i < 0 */ even(i + 2)
```

We can define an `odd` function in terms of `even`:

```
odd(i) = even(i+1)
```

We could then just define `evenList` recursively too:

```
evenList(nil) = true
eventList(x : xs) = even(x) & evenList(xs)
```

(I'm using `x : xs` to mean a list whose first element is `x` and whose remainder is `xs`. I'm using `nil` to mean an empty list.)

But maybe you're not allow to use a boolean `&` operator. What can we do instead?

Consider multiplying two numbers, i and j. What parity is the result, based on the parity of i and j? (Parity means oddness or evenness.)

- `even(i) & even(j) -> even(i*j)`
- `even(i) & odd(j) -> even(i*j)`
- `odd(i) & even(j) -> even(i*j)`
- `odd(i) & odd(j) -> odd(i*j)`

(I'm using `->` to means “implies”.) In other words, i*j is odd iff i is odd and j is odd.

So, if you multiply all of your input numbers together and the product is odd, then all of the inputs are odd. So we'll define a `product` function:

```
product(nil) = 1
product(x : xs) = x * product(xs)
```

And then we can define `oddList` like this:

```
oddList(xs) = odd(product(xs))
```

But how to know if all of the inputs are even? Even a single even input makes the product even.

The trick is to reverse the parity of all the inputs, and then reverse the parity of the result. You can reverse the parity by adding or subtracting one. Let i1 = i + 1 and j1 = j + 1. Then:

- `even(i) & even(j) -> odd(i1) & odd(j1) -> odd(i1 * j1) -> even(i1 * j1 + 1)`
- `even(i) & odd(j) -> odd(i1) & even(j1) -> even(i1 * j1) -> odd(i1 * j1 + 1)`
- `odd(i) & even(j) -> even(i1) & odd(j1) -> even(i1 * j1) -> odd(i1 * j1 + 1)`
- `odd(i) & odd(j) -> even(i1) & even(j1) -> even(i1 * j1) -> odd(i1 * j1 + 1)`

In other words, (i+1) * (j+1) + 1 is even **if and only if** i is even and j is even.

So, let's define a `product1` function that returns the product of all of its inputs, each incremented by 1 first:

```
product1(nil) = 1
product1(x : xs) = (x + 1) * product1(xs)
```

Then we can define `evenList` like this:

```
evenList(xs) = even(1 + product1(xs))
```

Comment: Great answer. However, do you really want SO to provide free homework answers to students who've made no attempt on their own?